# Infinite loop after looping program once caused by char

Tags: assembly, x86, scanf, nasm

I am writing a calculator in nasm and I am running into this issue that only happens after the user calculates two consecutive answers and inputs non-integer answer for the prompt called in the method "prompted".

prompted:

```
push prompt ;pushes prompt to stack
call printf ;call printf

add esp, 4 ;remove prompt off stack
push promptval ;push int that scanf will push to
push formatin ;push format for scanf
call scanf ;call scanf function

add esp, 8 ;remove promptval and formatin from stack

mov eax, dword [promptval] ;set eax as promptval

cmp eax, 1 ;figure out if promptval is 1 for 'yes'
je main ;if so then jump to main

call exit ;exit program if doesn't jump
```

this is the code which breaks only under these circumstances (just goes through the program infinitely continuing even when its supposed to prompt the user) just uses the last loops answers to all prompts under the infinite loop.

Comment: This is really a C question. Read about how `scanf` works. Hint: what it can not process gets left in the input buffer.

Comment: Not a [mcve] because you didn't include the `main` label, or the format string for `scanf`.  But `je main` is presumably going to re-run your whole program starting at the top of `main`.  If you want to check for `scanf` not converting any input, check its return value.